# Large number of small files Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Parameters of some machines are measured and uploaded via a web service to HDFS. Parameter values are saved in a file for each measurement, where a measurement has 1000 values in average.

The problem is - there is a large number of files. Only certain number of files is used for MapReduce job (for example, measurements from last month). Because of this I'm not able to merge them all into one large sequence file, since different files are needed in different time.

I understand that is bad to have a large number of small files, since the NameNode contains paths to all of them on HDFS (and keeps it in its memory) and on the other hand, each small file will result in a Mapper creation.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use `CombineSequenceFileInputFormat`? It should combine small files into one split and create smaller number of mappers. Documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineSequenceFileInputFormat.html

Comment: To be honest, I'm not very experienced with Hadoop, but I understand that there may be some problems with that approach. For example, the references to all the files on HDFS would be still saved in NameNode memory, is that correct? Are there other problems as well, when using CombineSequenceFileInputFormat?

Comment: Yes, storage of a large amount of small files in HDFS is bad idea. You can merge small files into one sequence file per hour (or day). If you will use file's timestamp as key and file's content as value then in mapper you will be able to filter files that not included in specified time range.

Comment: So you are suggesting to run a MapReduce job and emit only the files in the specified range from the mapper? But I'll still have the problem of many mapper tasks for that job, I guess that such a thing could be tolerated? And on the other hand, I will need to leave the original files on HDFS, to merge them next time I need it, which will have an impact on the NameNode the whole time. Any comment about that? I guess I'll have to do something like that, if there isn't a better solution. What do you think of using HBase or something like that, to query by timestamp? Would same problems exist?

Comment: you could try HAR(hadoop archive) to pack small files into single archieve so that reduces the overhead of NameNode to maintain too many small files, and use CombineFileInputFormat over HAR to limit the number of mappers dispatched.

Comment: @sureshsiva Thank you for your suggestion, it seems best so far, but there is still the problem that I would need to HAR the files every time I need to run the job, since it most probably runs on different subset of files. Would you recommend this approach, or maybe using something like Cassandra, to save the content (which is actually an array of numbers)?

Comment: @pera, i understand your concern, could you tell me if the subset of files which alone needs to be processed have anything in common with their file names? .. So that we can use the PathFilter to filter only the required files to the job...

Comment: @sureshsiva Well, it could contain the timestamp, so they can be filtered based on it. The problem is - today I need the files that were uploaded 30 days ago, but I don't need the ones before. On the other hand, the timewindow can be specified for each job, so for another job I could need files from last six months, so I need all the original files. That's why I'm thinking to put the content to Cassandra, what do you think?

Comment: @pera, Obviously Cassandra will be best suit for time series data and if it is fine to you to push these contents to Cassandra. Apart from this I would recommend the MapFile format to merge small files with timestampe as key and to get the required files by timestamp using the lookup options available with MapFile.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer: You can use SeaweedFS https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs (I am working on this). It has special optimization for large number of small files.

HDFS actually has good support to delegate file storage to other file systems. Just add a SeaweedFS hadoop jar. See https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs/wiki/Hadoop-Compatible-File-System

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the required files into one temporal file that is deleted once analyzed. I think you can create this very easily in a script.

Anyway, make the numbers: such a big file will be also splited into several pieces whose size will be the blocksize (`dfs.blocksize` parameter a `hdfs-defaul.xml`), and each one of these pieces will be assigned to a mapper. I mean, depending on the blocksize and the average "small file" size, maybe the gain is not so great.

Comment: Well, the gain should be great, since the file may have a size of 8KB, and the default block size is 64MB.

Comment: So, I think your concatenating script must be smart: you must concatenate small files at least until the blocksize is reached.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I would like to avoid concatenating large number of files each time a job needs to be executed. But, on the other hand, I would probably need different subset of files each time... (for example, if job starts eight hours later it needs files that were added in the meanwhile and it doesn't need the files from window size - 8h).